# What's behind the amazing colour combinations in pests & insects?

Tags: zoology, pigmentation

What's behind the amazing colour combinations in pests & insects ? Do this colour combination signals any character/ poison of the pest/insect ?

Comment: What pest? Which insect? Bright colors often indicate poisonous animals but you'll need to be much more specific for us to be able to answer you.

Comment: Or [that's what they *want* you to think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batesian_mimicry)...

Comment: @Oreotrephes sneaky buggers :).

Comment: Why Close vote? I think, its answerable!!